# How to calculate if a triangle is back-facing or front facing in Vulkan

Tags: graphics, vulkan, vector-graphics

In this page:
https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/man/html/VkFrontFace.html
They give this equation:
[image]

How would you apply that formula for example to a triangle with these coordinates?:

p0(-0.5, -0.5)

p1(0.5, -0.5)

p2(0.5, 0.5)

Does it expand to something like this?

(-1/2) ( ((p0.x)(p1.y) - (p1.x)(p0.y)) + ((p1.x)(p2.y) - (p2.x)(p1.y)) + ((p2.x)(p0.y) - (p0.x)(p2.y)) )

(-1/2) ( ((-0.5)(-0.5) - (0.5)(-0.5)) + ((0.5)(0.5) - (0.5)(-0.5)) + ((0.5)(-0.5) - (-0.5)(0.5)) )

(-1/2) ( (0.5) + (0.5) + (0.0) )

-0.5

The sign being negative so that it is front-facing since "a triangle with negative area is considered front-facing."?

And if so, how does this coorespond to the normals calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The triangle seems to be like this:

[image: triangle with winding]

The winding seems to be clockwise, so with the defaults (counter-clockwise) it would be backfacing.

The formula is not something invented by Vulkan. It is basic formula for area of a triangle. The classic form is something like this: **0.5|AB×AC|**. **A**, **B**, and **C**, are the vertices in this specified order, and so **AB** and **AC** are line segments\vectors:

[image]

For our purposes we don't need area exactly, we only need the direction of the normal. They just happen to be almost the same thing. We get a normal by calculating the cross product: **AB×AC**. That yields the vector
**(0, 0, AB.x⋅AC.y - AB.y⋅AC.x)**.

Magnitude of a vector with only one component is the absolute value of that. We skip that absolute value operation, to get a signed "area". So we have just:
**AB.x⋅AC.y - AB.y⋅AC.x**

**AB** is simply **B-A**, and similarly **AC = C-A**, so substituting that and processing the multiplication, that yields:
**Ax⋅By-Bx⋅Ay + Bx⋅Cy-Cx⋅By + Cx⋅Ay-Ax⋅Cy**
This matches the **Σ** in the specification.

With your numbers, that yields **(-0.5⋅-0.5)-(0.5⋅-0.5) + (0.5⋅0.5)-(0.5⋅-0.5) + (0.5⋅-0.5)-(-0.5⋅0.5) = 1**.

The ½ multiplication obviously does not matter to us, since it is not sign-changing. But anyway, that makes it **½×1 = 0.5**. That checks out: area of a 1x1 right-angled triangle **is** 0.5.

The **y** coordinates poining down causes mirroring, therefore changes the perceived direction of winding:

[image]

Therefore we must swap the sign in the equation: **-0.5(AB.x⋅AC.y - AB.y⋅AC.x)**. So we get -0.5.

In case of `VK_FRONT_FACE_COUNTER_CLOCKWISE`, the frontface is the one with positive area, so we are indeed seeing the backface.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, for this part:
"The y coordinates poining down causes mirroring, therefore changes the perceived direction of winding"
What does that mean?

Comment: @OwenZhang Compare the second and third image in the answer. Look at the direction of the winding arrow. This is why the equation has minus sign compared to the conventional one. Typically conventional math looks at things from +Z. Right-handed graphics (typically with Y pointing down) looks at it from -Z. It changes what we consider "front", because we are looking from the other direction.

Comment: I wouldn't call counter-clockwise the "default" just because VK_FRONT_FACE_COUNTER_CLOCKWISE is equal to zero.  I suppose if you initialize the rasterization struct to all zeros and don't populate the variable then it becomes the default, but that seems like bad practice.

Comment: @Jherico There are other reasons. It is default in OpenGL, as it is default convention in general (aka right-hand rule).